# Surjectivity of a piecewise function $f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Function $f$ is defined as $f: (-1, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$.
$$
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
-x/(x-1),&x\geq 0
\\
x/(x+1),&x \leq 0
\end{cases}
$$

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$. How would I prove that there exists a   $x\in (-1, 1)$ such  that $f(x) = y$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $x \geq 0$, then $f(x) \geq 0$, and if $x\leq 0$, then $f(x) \leq 0$ as well. So let's split this into two parts:

1. $y \geq 0$. In that case, take $x/(1-x) = y \Leftrightarrow x = y/(1+y)$. Note that $x\geq0$ and $x < 1$ in this case, so this choice works.
2. $y < 0$. In this case, take $x/(1+x) = y \Leftrightarrow x = y/(1-y)$. Note that $x < 0$ and $x > -1$ in this case, so this choice works.

Basically, you would have to split the range of the function into several sets, where each piecewise function's range corresponds to the partition.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guide you through how I would approach this sort of problem.

First you have to test the water. Try some positive and negative numbers and see where they are mapped to.

$$f\left(\frac12\right)=\frac{\frac12}{\frac12}=1\\
f\left(-\frac12\right)=\frac{-\frac12}{\frac12}=-1$$

Okay, that's a bit "too" well-behaved, let's try $\pm\frac1\pi$ instead.

$$f\left(\frac1\pi\right)=\frac{\frac1\pi}{\frac{\pi-1}{\pi}}=\frac1{\pi-1}\\
f\left(-\frac1\pi\right)=\frac{-\frac1\pi}{\frac{\pi-1}{\pi}}=-\frac1{\pi-1}$$

Okay, that gives us sort of a clue here. We need to separate the cases if $y<0$ and if $y>0$, and of course the $y=0$ case as well.

If $y=0$ then $f(0)=0$ and we're done.

So now suppose $y>0$, then write $y=\frac x{1-x}$ then $x=y(1-x)=y-xy$, and therefore $x+xy=y=x(1+y)$ which means $x=\frac y{1+y}$.

Do the same for $y<0$, and you're about done. You may want to clean this up a bit, of course.